# Python: How can I sort the values in a dictionary according to size and display the 3 largest values?

Tags: python, dictionary

For example: I have the following string s = "I do not understand this". I would now like to display the 3 most frequently occurring characters in the string s, without using "sorted" or packages.
I have the following code:

```
s = "I do not understand this"
d = {}
spaces = " "

for b in s:
    if b not in spaces:
        if b not in d:
            d[b] = 1
        else:
            d[b] = d[b]+ 1
```

But I don't know how to go on.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own list with `(key, value)` tuples where you'll define the order. You'll then be able to convert this list back to a sorted dictionary:

```
s = "I do not understand this"
d = {}

for b in s:
    if b != " ":
        d[b] = d.get(b, 0) + 1

# the sorting part:
most_occurring_letters = [list(d.items())[0]] # list with first key/value of your dict

# going through all other keys
for b in list(d)[1:]:
    for i, (letter, count) in enumerate(most_occurring_letters):
        if d[b] >= d[letter]:
            most_occurring_letters.insert(i, (b, d[b]))
            break

print(most_occurring_letters[:3]) # the 3 most occurring elements
```

Output:

```
[('t', 3), ('n', 3), ('d', 3)]
```

Convert to dict to get a sorted dictionary:

```
print(dict(most_occurring_letters))
```

Output:

```
{'t': 3, 'n': 3, 'd': 3, 's': 2, 'o': 2, 'i': 1, 'h': 1, 'a': 1, 'r': 1, 'e': 1, 'u': 1, 'I': 1}
```